# 0.1uf electrolytic substitute

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

I am replacing all electrolytic capacitors in an old CB radio but can't find a local source for this capacitor. Is there another type I can use in its place? Does it have to be an electrolytic type? Thanks.

Comment: I see electrolytic 0.1µF caps starting at a dime apiece on mouser.com.

Comment: MLCC 0.1uF caps?

Comment: Electrolytic capacitors are almost never used for their electrolytic properties, only their capacitance.

Comment: Yeash...You can buy bags of 1,000 for a few dollars from Digikey/Mouser/Allied, etc. Stay with ceramic SMD for such low values.

Comment: They need to be polarised, so should I use tantalum?

Comment: "need" to be polarised?!?  No such thing.

Comment: What is the voltage rating?

Comment: 16 volts is written on the parts list.

Answer (score 1):

0.1 uF electrolytic caps are already or are almost obsolete

The lower cost solid Radial 0.1uF Tantalums have poor ESR (12~26 ohm)

Radial ceramics are fine.
https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/vishay-bc-components/K104K15X7RF53L2/BC3324-ND/2820506  $10 / 100pc